# swiftでfatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional valueが出た時のデバッグ方法

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

swiftで実装をしていて、ビルドは通るものの、
アプリ起動後に、
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
のエラーが出る場合、ソースコードのどこが原因かを探るデバッグはどのように進めていくのが定石なのでしょうか?

よくこのエラーではまるのですが、どのファイルの何行目でこのエラーが起きているのかまで表示されないため、毎回ソースコードを全部見て原因を探っていて
もっと効率的なデバッグ方法があればと思い質問してみました。

追記
具体的には↓のような画面でとまります。
breakpoint navigator でException Breakpoint を追加しても特に変わりありません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

示されてる画面の左側のペインにはスタックフレーム（クラッシュが発生する地点までにどのようなメソッドが呼ばれたか）が表示されています。

上の方が新しくて、下に行くほど、過去にさかのぼることになります。

直接のクラッシュが発生しているのは運悪くシステムのコードに当たっていますが、一つさかのぼると、おそらくご自分で書かれたコードのクラッシュを引き起こしている箇所が表示されると思います。

↓ 下記に示すように赤く囲ったところをクリックしてみてください。
画像では右が切れているので詳細はわかりませんが、おそらく、`iBeaconCentral`というクラスのテーブルビューのデリゲートメソッドのどこかが表示されると思います。

基本的にはそこがクラッシュの直接の原因です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ありがとうございます！教えていただいた方法で、無事どこが原因か特定することが出来ました！
(質問とは関係ないのですが、先日のiOSオールスター勉強会の講演拝見しておりました。このような質問に答えてくださって感謝しています！)

Comment: @tatsuya.yokohama さん。もしこの解答が問題の解決に役立ったのでしたら、ぜひ解答にチェックを付けましょう。回答者と質問者に評価ポイントが加わりますし、コミュニティの為にもなります。どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

特に何も設定しなくても、以下の様な感じでエラーの原因となった行が表示されないでしょうか・・・？

[image: エラーが発生]

うまく動作しない場合、以下の設定でどうにか出来るかもしれません。

[image: 例外にブレークポイントを設定]

Comment: ありがとうございます。質問本文に追記させていただきましたが、行が表示されません。確かに表示されるエラーも見たことがあるのですが、表示されないのも結構有ります。Add Exception Breakpointも試してみましたが特に変わりないです。